# How to load statuses from Twitter API? TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, twitter

I was successfully pulling tweets from the Twitter API until **I decided to put the keys/tokens in a separate configuration file.** As I plan on uploading the main file to Github.
The solutions on StackOverflow that I found so far didn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

---

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import json
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configpath = r'config.py'
config.read(configpath)
consumer_key = config.get('logintwitter', 'consumer_key')
consumer_secret = config.get('logintwitter', 'consumer_secret')
access_key = config.get('logintwitter', 'access_key')
access_secret = config.get('logintwitter', 'access_secret')


consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret) #twitter: sign me in
access_token = oauth.Token(key=access_key, secret=access_secret) #grant me access
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token) #object return

timeline_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"
response, data = client.request(timeline_endpoint)

tweets = json.loads(data) #take a JSON string convert it to dictionary structure:
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet["text"])
```

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/twiiter2/twitterconnect.py", line 24,
>   in 
>       print(tweet["text"]) TypeError: string indices must be integers

I tried changing the json.loads() method as well as the content in print(tweet["text"])

Humbled for anyon to point me in the right direction.

> Thank you!

Comment: When I print 'data' I receive: `b'{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}'`